# Create a macro for Microsoft Access via Interop

Tags: c#, ms-access, macros, office-interop

Is it possible to create a new macro using C# using the Interop library in Microsoft Access in a similar fashion as Word, Excel, or PowerPoint?  In the other applications, you have access to `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop._VBComponent`, which allows you to inject new macros, through the `Document`, `Worksheet`, or `Presentation` classes.  It doesn't look like Access has anything similar to this.  Access has an `AllMacros` list, but it appears to be read-only.  I know how to execute the macro once it's in the project, but I need to be able to add macros dynamically.  I would greatly appreciate anyone that could point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from answers.microsoft.com:

*A macro in Access is a special database object, unlike in other Office applications where a macro is simply a VBA procedure without arguments. As far as I know you can't create an Access macro programmatically.* ***-HansV MVP (April 27, 2011)***

There is another answer posted at the [same question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/how-to-programmatically-create-a-ms-access-macro/177cf24e-5870-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=c46f263f-9270-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) that says you can create new code/VBA objects using the VB Extensibility Library.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent all day looking for that kind of information.

Answer (score 7):

Because of HK1's answer, I was able to do exactly what I needed.  I wanted to post my code because there is little to no information anywhere on how to do this.  I will leave HK1's post marked as the answer because he is what lead me to this.

**Programmatically adding VB Modules to MS-Access via Interop**

```
try
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    accessApp.Visible = true;

    accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(filePath);

    // Get the active VBProject item
    VBProject project = accessApp.VBE.VBProjects.Item(1);

    VBComponent module = project.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

    module.CodeModule.AddFromString(script);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Trust or the VBA Project Module has not been enabled.
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the below exception is thrown by the interop.

"Additional information: Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted."