# Is there a way to add vba macro code to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a problem with a existing macro function,so what I have to do is to pass a macro to excel I mean add the function(Ex: a()) to excel,and run the function("a()") added.

Note:I have path of the excel where i`ll have to add macro into. Please be clear about the answers.

How to do this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar question regarding Access.  Excel works just about the same way except you can acess the VBProject right off of the _Workbook object, you should be able to get what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020923/create-a-macro-for-microsoft-access-via-interop  I wrote out the code I used below the answer.

Comment: @Middas: Thanks for your answer. How can I add my macro function to a existing module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- install Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable for your office version
- Add reference to Assemblies -> Extensions ->Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.VBE.Interop

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
  using ExcelInterop = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
      public partial class AddExcelMacro : Form
      {
          public AddExcelMacro()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              AddMacro();
          }

          public void AddMacro()
          {
              try
              {
                  // open excel file 
                  const string excelFile = @"c:\temp\VBA\test.xlsm";
                  var excelApplication = new ExcelInterop.Application { Visible = true };
                  var targetExcelFile = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);

                  // add standart module to file
                  var newStandardModule = targetExcelFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
                  var codeModule = newStandardModule.CodeModule;

                  // add vba code to module
                  var lineNum = codeModule.CountOfLines + 1;
                  var macroName = "Button1_Click";
                  var codeText = "Public Sub " + macroName +"()" + "\r\n";
                  codeText += "  MsgBox \"Hi from Excel\"" + "\r\n";
                  codeText += "End Sub";

                  codeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);
                  targetExcelFile.Save();

                  // run the macro
                  var macro = string.Format("{0}!{1}.{2}", targetExcelFile.Name, newStandardModule.Name, macroName);
                  excelApplication.Run(macro);

                  excelApplication.Quit();

              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                  throw;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Daniel:Thanks for the answer. I didnt get this point Add reference to Assemblies -> Extensions ->Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.VBE.Interop" (second point).

Comment: Daniel: Sorry for that,i have accepted the answer. Now please tel me what is it you `ve mentioned. I have installed PIA.

Comment: Can`t we just add macro,without installing PIA`s and other stuffs? I think it`s hectic,and i`m not sure if i have to install the same in server too.

Comment: If you want to add macro code to excel file from c# you have to install Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable for your office version. Have a look here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508. After that add references to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.VBE.Interop in your c# project. Is this understandable to you? My english is bad :-).

Comment: Daniel:No,you are totally good wit english. You mean to say i have to download these manually?

Comment: Daniel: I`m getting error for the namespace "ExcelInterop = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;". It says like excel doesn`t exist in the current namespace.

Comment: And just to be sure, you added the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel into your c# project?

Comment: How can we do this for protected workbook/sheet??? I tried doing "excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFile,0,false,5,"iiaa78@");" still dont work. please suggest an answer.

Comment: Have you tried named arguments? E.g. excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(Filename: excelFile, Password: "Password123");

Comment: Daniel: Unprotecting it doesn`t throw err, but it still not unprotecting the sheet.

Comment: I got error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted
"

Comment: @hienbuithanh88 read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/282830) article.