# Controls added by VSTO working without Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, excel-2010, vsto

Suppose you have an Excel VSTO add-in that creates a control. Is there a way to make that control work in an instance of Excel that doesn't have the add-in?

Simplification of the problem: an add-in creates a button..

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    var button = this.Controls.AddButton(10, 10, 50, 50, "My Button");
    button.Text = "My Button";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
 }

 void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("I was clicked!");
 }
```

the document is then saved with that button and emailed to another user. When the other user opens the document and clicks that button, nothing happens.

How do you make the button work on everyone else's computer?

Comment: VSTO Add-in can't be shipped as part of the Excel file. You need to install this Add-in on all computers where you need to run this functionality.

Comment: Then perhaps there's a way to have a button turn the workbook into a macro workbook and insert a button with ref to macro?

Comment: Actually... found this re adding macro using vsto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15201483/2043621

Comment: Since I was unable to locate Microsoft documentations stating it isn't possible, I'd love to see the docs saying it won't work. I'd of course also accept that ("no") as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I develop on Word, not Excel, but as I see it, your options are:

1. Create a document/template-level VSTO Add-In. Every workbook created based on a template (xltm) can have the same button, and it can call a macro or just run code. It's fairly straightforward, but your recipient would need to have the Add-In as well.
2. Essentially the same as #1 but it's application-level, so it still has to be installed on your recipient's computers, but the button is always there, they don't have to make it themselves. You can conditionally show it, if you want it only in certain workbooks.
3. Create a macro in a workbook, save it and remove the VSTO customizations from the workbook, and tell your recipients to run the macro. They can add a button to run it, on a custom ribbon tab, but you can't create the button automatically because changing the ribbon through code is not supported. It's also shared across all documents so it would show up in every excel document, depending on how it's created (you'd want to make it in the Excel equivalent of the Normal.dotm template). They can't make it only show up sometimes.
4. This is pretty similar to #3 but the way the macro is delivered may make more sense to you. Word has a way to create a macro in a document and place it in the startup folder, and all documents opened by that user on that system would have the macro available. Excel has something similar, a [personal workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). You can probably find a way to provide this personal workbook to your recipients with your macro already in it. They would still need to create any ribbon buttons themselves.

It seems like you really don't want your users to have the Add-In, so #3 or #4 seem like the best options.