# Is there a way to change excel chart titles across all the sheets using vba macro code to excel?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, vba

I'm trying to edit chart titles of approx 72 sheets in a go using excel VBA macro function but the issue is that the excel is disabling up the macros of the excel sheet if it shared across the network and sometimes the VBA macro in the excel sheet is not working.

So according to the solution found here:
[Is there a way to add vba macro code to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196534/is-there-a-way-to-add-vba-macro-code-to-excel)

I made the following code to change the title but it is not working as expected.

```
var newStandardModule = xlWorkBook2.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
var codeModule = newStandardModule.CodeModule;
var lineNum = codeModule.CountOfLines + 1;
var macroName = "ReplaceAll";
var codeText = "Sub " + macroName + "()" + "\r\n";
codeText += " For Each sh In Worksheets \r\n For Each ch In sh.ChartObjects \r\n If ch.Chart.HasTitle Then \r\n ch.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = VBA.Replace(ch.Chart.ChartTitle.Text, \"CurrentSKU_HD_Model_FW\",\""+sku+"\""+", 1) \r\n End If \r\n Next \r\n Next" + "\r\n";
codeText += "End Sub";
codeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);
var macro = string.Format("{0}!{1}.{2}", xlWorkBook2.Name, newStandardModule.Name, macroName);
xlWorkBook2.Application.Run(macro);
xlWorkBook2.SaveAs(filename2);
```

Can someone let me know where I'm wrong?

EDIT:I tried adding in the same macro using C# like given in the answered question,it executed perfectly but when I'm trying to execute my inserted macro, it isn't working when called through the C# code. Plus the vba macro that I inserted working perfectly fine when going to the Excel Macro File and executing it.

Comment: A problem description of "but it is not working as expected" is not very useful.  (It's actually implied by the fact that you are posting a question.)  Please provide **some** information so that we can assist you.

Comment: I tried adding in the same macro using C# like given in the answered question,it executed perfectly but when I'm trying to execute my inserted macro, it isn't working when called through the C# code. Plus the vba macro that I inserted working perfectly fine when going to the Excel Macro File and executing it.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `macro` at the point when you try to `Run` it?  (And please edit your previous comment into the question itself - comments have a habit of disappearing.)

Comment: Sure, edited.The value of macro is (WLGPCI_Template.xlsm!Module7.ReplaceAll) at the time of execution. where WLGPCI_Template.xlsm is the Macro Enabled Excel File.