# Is it possible to create an 'access' macro through automation?

Tags: vba, automation

I have been searching this for a while without any positives . We can create new modules, form ,report,  but macros .Can we at all do this? This post asks the same question but answers another one.

"[Create a macro for Microsoft Access via Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020923/create-a-macro-for-microsoft-access-via-interop) "

here VBA module is being added  not macro.

Theoretically it seems feasible as macro is an access object so why we cant do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can create macros via vba.

There is an object AllMacros (Application.currentproject.allmacros) and its members are representations of the individual macros in your project - but they are of the type Object, thus there doesn't seem to be any vba representation of the macro object.
You also can't import macros, autogenerate them or convert from vba to macros... So it seems pretty obvious ms isnt encouraging using them and hasn't done anything for us to create them

Comment: thanx for ur reply.One thing that's bothering me is that how does access recovery softwares recreate macros if its not possible.i mean even a blanck macro..are there any workarounds other than VBA.

Comment: Access doesn't need to use a specified interface to create/recreate internal things. The fact that you can script almost everything in access doesn't mean, the programm itself can only do what is scriptable. If you want to do it hardcore, you could use a bunch of sendkeys though...